# c# / exchange: Recurrence with interruption

Tags: c#, exchange-server, recurrence, appointment

I want to create a weekly recurring series of appointments for one year in Exchange with c#.

Every 7 or 8 weeks holidays will interrupt that series one or two times.

I have a `List<Datetime> holidays` with all my holidays in it.

The easiest way seems to be creating single appointments for every relevant week. Is it good practice? Do I have to deal with performance issues? Is the network traffic significantly higher as working with recurring appointments?

Alternatively: Is it possible to define recurring appointments and then check against my holiday-list to implement interruptions in that series?

How can I do this?
Thx
zacktell